# Non $l^p$ type of norm on sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been reading about norms on sequences, and all the norm I've seen are some form of $l^p$ norms (sometimes with weights). Are there any other "kinds" of norms on sequences?

Comment: I recommend Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri:"Classical Banach spaces"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a convex, non-decreasing continuous function $M:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that fullfills the conditions $$M(0)=0,\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}M(t)=\infty$$ the set of sequences $$\ell_M(\mathbb{N})=\{x\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}:\exists \rho>0:\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}M(\frac{|x_j|}{\rho})<\infty\}$$
is equipped with a norm: $$|x|=\inf\{\rho>0:\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}M(\frac{|x_j|}{\rho})\leq 1\}$$
that turns it into a Banach-space, which is called an Orlicz space, and that coincides with the well known spaces $\ell^P(\mathbb{N})$ for $M(t)=t^p$ where $p\geq1$.